# how to execute a python script from javascript in splunk?

Tags: javascript, python, splunk

I need to run a [python](https://www.python.org/) script from javascript (html file), the project is deployed in [splunk](http://www.splunk.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Via NodeJs we can communicate with python script.

i used this [python-shell](https://www.npmjs.org/package/python-shell) plugin to run python script from JS.

Very Useful one.