# How to execute python script from javascript ,Needs to be implemented in splunk UI

Tags: javascript, python, splunk

Kindly help me to execute python script from javascript.
    I will be calling Javascript from Splunk UI.
    What are the splunk configuration changes needs to be done  ?
    TIA.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to execute a python script from javascript in splunk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25240847/how-to-execute-a-python-script-from-javascript-in-splunk)

Comment: You can take a look at this stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21915814/calling-a-python-script-from-javascript-both-local-files.